# Handling Nullable Properties when posting to a ComboBox DropDownList

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a custom class Diary, which has a nullable property DeadlineType

On one of my Forms I have a ComboBox in DropDownList mode, which is populated with all the possible values that DeadlineType can take.  When a Diary is selected, the form is populated with all the properties, but I have an issue with the DeadlineType property in that, when it is null, it requires more code than I believe it should i.e.

```
if (amendDiary.DeadlineType != null)    
{
    cboDeadlineType.Text = amendDiary.DeadlineType.ToString();
}
else
{
    cboDeadlineType.Text = null;
}
```

I am sure there must be a more concise way to achieve this, or certainly hope so, because this scenario is repeated a lot throughout my application i.e. posting nulls to ComboBoxes.

I did try

```
cboDeadlineType.Text = amendDiary.DeadlineType.ToString() ?? null
```

But that gives an 'Object not set to an instance' error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
cboDeadlineType.Text = (amendDiary.DeadlineType ?? "").ToString();
```

Note that setting the `ComboBox.Text` to `null` means the same as setting it to `""` (The combo Text is empty in both cases).

Another solution is use the `Convert.ToString` method:

```
cboDeadlineType.Text = Convert.ToString(amendDiary.DeadlineType);
```

With that solution, if the input is `null`, the `cboDeadlineType.Text` is assigned exactly to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
cboDeadlineType.Text = amendDiary.DeadlineType!=null ?amendDiary.ToString() :"";
```